# CASE in WHERE clause returns Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running this code:

```
SELECT hID 
  FROM logonsHistory
 WHERE aIDs NOT LIKE '%''101''%' AND
 CASE src 

WHEN 0 THEN 

uID IN(29,41,42,45,49,50,57,73,83,107,166,349,356,367,375,376,416,471,472,473,474,481) 

END
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'

I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: right... because those numbers represent clientIDs. when the src = 0 (Clients table) then uID IN(clientIDs). If the src is something else, then it's not a uID isn't a clientID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have to use `CASE` please test this

```
SELECT hID
  FROM logonsHistory
 WHERE aIDs NOT LIKE '%''101''%'
       AND ( (src = 0 --scr is 0 => must have uid in the list
              AND UID IN (29,41,42,45,49,50,57,73,83,107,166,349,356,367,375,376,416,471,472,473,474,481))
            OR src <> 0) --else src is not 0 and there is no additional condition
```

i have a doubt on your `not like` condition have you tested it alone?

Comment: yea.. that works just fine. It's when i added the CASE when everything blew up

Comment: And you need to use `CASE`? or this awser your requierement?

Comment: What's gonna happen when src is not 0, isn't it going to ignore it?

Comment: What it? I add comments in my anwser. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` statement is not appropriate in this case.  Just use a simple `OR` condition:

```
SELECT hID 
  FROM logonsHistory
 WHERE aIDs NOT LIKE '%''101''%'
 AND (
    src <> 0 -- add a COALESCE here if src can be NULL
    OR uID IN(29,41,42,45,49,50,57,73,83,107,166,349,356,367,375,376,416,471,472,473,474,481) 
 )
```

... which basically is the equivalent of only applying the `uID` filtering if `src = 0`, which is what you appeared to be trying to accomplish with your query.

Comment: this is more or less correct. However if src is null, it will not pass validation unless uID has a match

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Agreed.  It all depends on whether `src` allows nulls or not.  In which case, a little extra care is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `when` part of a `case` statement should select a single value. what you are trying to do is to check for a condition.

Or if you are checking for `uid` in those values, you should do

```
 case when src = 0 then
                        case when uID IN (29,41,42,45,49,50,57,73,83,107,166,349,356,367,375,376,416,471,472,473,474,481)
                        then 'It is a Client ID'
                        -- add another when or else part here if required
                        end
 else 'Not a UID and not a Client ID'
 end
```

Comment: I want to say CASE src 0 then do an AND uID IN(). How do I do this then?

Comment: is this what you are trying to do?  nested `case`?

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is what you are looking for

```
WHERE aIDs NOT LIKE '%''101''%' or
( 
src = 0 
AND
uID IN(29,41,42,45,49,50,57,73,83,107,166,349,356,367,375,376,416,471,472,473,474,481
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your statement is not formatted properly. you placed a condition rather than a value to set within "When 0 then ...... END

the uID IN(29,41,42,45,49,50,57,73,83,107,166,349,356,367,375,376,416,471,472,473,474,481) you have there is a condition and shouldn't have been there